# How to hide menu bar icon without using external apps?

Tags: macos, menu-bar

I want to remove an icon from showing in the menu bar of a 3rd party usb wireless receiver. Anyone knows how to do it without using an external app on macOS?

Comment: Usually you can disable the menubar icon in the preferences of the 3rd party app. Which app is it?

Comment: See if the app has a preference setting not to show in the menu bar or close the app. If it's implemented using the NSMenuExtra API vs. NSStatusItem API, you can press and hold ⌘ and drag it off the menu.

Comment: @MoritzPetersen it's a driver for a wireless USB

Comment: @user3439894 I'll edit the question, it's a wireless USB driver that came with it